# Getting lightweight SSO token from PingFederate using WCF or WIF

Tags: c#, wcf, single-sign-on, ws-security, pingfederate

I'm writing client using WCF for demo settings provided by PingFederate in the similar way as described in this post ([Getting a Token from PingFederate using WIF](http://travisspencer.com/blog/2010/03/getting-a-token-from-pingfeder.html)).
My problem is that on the second step I need to exchange SAML token to lightweight SSO token on SP.
I'm getting exception while serialization of response from the SP

```
ID3135: The element 'TokenType' with namespace 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512' has value 'BASE64BINARY' which is not an absolute URI.
```

as I understand WS2007FederationHttpBinding can't handle that type of tokens.

I'm looking for explanation how such scenario should be handled.

The the client code is as following (after getting SAML token from IDP)

```
 var binding = new WS2007FederationHttpBinding();
  binding.Security.Mode = WSFederationHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
  binding.Security.Message.IssuedKeyType = SecurityKeyType.BearerKey;
  binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(binding, new EndpointAddress(SP_EndPoint));
  factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
  factory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;
 var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
  {
    RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
    //AppliesTo = new EndpointReference(@"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous"),
  };

  RequestSecurityTokenResponse rstr;
  var channel = factory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(idpToken);
  SecurityToken spToken = channel.Issue(rst, out rstr);
  return spToken;
```